# Вытащить данные из атрибута data формы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Всем привет. Есть форма в блоке с классом '.product-frame' и атрибутом data-product_variations с кучей параметров. Ниже я показал, что в ней содержится, если смотреть через консоль. Мне необходимо извлечь из нее формируемый код, чтобы с ним взаимодействовать `<span class="price"><span class="amount">здесь указана стоимость</span>` - это можно как-нить сделать?

```js
     $('.product-frame').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       var variations_form = $this.find('.variations_form').attr('data-product_variations');
       console.log(variations_form);
     }
     })
```

```html
<div class="product-frame">
  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="3351" data-product_variations="..">
    <div class="single_variation">
    </div>
</div>

<!--То, что получаю в console.log -->
[{"variation_id":3354,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":260000,"display_regular_price":260000,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"large"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","price_html":"
<span class=\ "price\"><span class=\ "amount\">260.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":"","backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"},{"variation_id":3355,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":160000,"display_regular_price":160000,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"medium"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"amount\">160.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":"","backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"},{"variation_id":3356,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":80000,"display_regular_price":80000,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"small"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"amount\">80.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":"","backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"}]
```

Comment: фактически в форме есть `"price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"amount\">160.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>"` к которому и нужно обратиться. через find я его нашел - а как теперь обратиться к содержимому?

Comment: почему не получается обратиться через `var variations_form = $this.find('.variations_form').attr('data-product_variations'); console.log(variations_form['price_html']);`   ?

Comment: У вас там ошибка, после экранирующего символа пробел.в самом первом объекте у свойства "price_html", поэтому возможно ошибка вылетает. А так, можете обращать к свойству таким образом

`json_string[0]['price_html']`, где json_string - это переменная, которая хранит данные ( получим свойство первого объекта )

Comment: @ThisMan т.е. имеете ввиду вот так?
`var variations_form = $this.find('.variations_form').attr('data-product_variations');
   console.log(variations_form[0]['price_html']);`
так не прокатывает - пишет undefine

Comment: variations_form[0] выводит первый символ массива '[', если 1 - то второй '{', 2 - 3ий '"' и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас же там строка, вам нужно привести эту строку к JSON формату, тогда можно будет ее распарсить `JSON.parse(string)`, вернет объект, где уже будет работать конструкция `variations_form[0]['price_html']`, то есть надо примерно так:

```
var form = $this.find('.variations_form');
var variationsForm = form.attr('data-  product_variations'); // еще строка
var variationsFormParsed = JSON.parse(variations_form); // уже объект
console.log(variationsFormParsed[0]['price_html']);
```

P.S. Используйте camelCase - это по js-овски))

Comment: отлично! А еще, может подскажите: если получаю строчку `<span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000 руб.</span></span>` как обратиться к классу `price` ? `find` ведь не срабатывает

Comment: @Вася, можно создать виртуальный дом и оттуда извлекать, либо через регулярки, смотря зачем вам нужен этот класс

Comment: для того,чтобы у него можно было поизменять стили, в данном случае высоту `$(this).filter(".price").css("top" , (height+32)+"px");` а виртуальный дом что из себя будет представлять?